# How To do inverse this relationship in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Am New in laravel and am trying to reverse the following relationship
so here is my problem basically i have created two models
Country and 
Contact

So here what i do is created a function in contact model so that i can fetch country acc to user ID
here is my contact model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    public function country(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
 }

  }
```

So now i want to reverse this relationship i.e i want to get Users info acc. to country

here what i have done so far:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$c = Country::all();
 return $c;
 });
```

Comment: It depends on what of relation you are trying to established. like one-to-one, one-to-many

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a one-to-many relation, [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) says you need a `hasMany` relationship, so what you want to do is add

```
public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
}
```

to your Country model, you can then get all contacts belonging to that country by using `$contacts = $c->contacts`.

If you want a one-to-one relation you have to change `hasMany` to `hasOne`, and for clarity change the function name from `function contacts()` to `function contact()`.

Comment: Thank You very much It's Working. Am trying harder to understand this relationships but it's really confusing..

Comment: @HimanshuRahi. Take time to go through the laravel documentation. Eloquent Model especially